# Getting infinite session on Facebook

Tags: language-agnostic, facebook

Please help me out in getting infinite session on facebook. I am getting a session logged out or invalid session key while testing my application.

Does this infinite session apply to anyone who logs in?

Answer (score 3):

i believe the infinite session is not used anymore.

instead, you can indlude the general include.php which will require the user log in if he has been logged out for being stagnant. the "New Design Platform Changes" wiki page says

```
*  We will still grant infinite sessions to your Web applications for users on the old profile.
* Users who added your application on the old profile who then switch to the new profile, will continue to have an infinite session.
* We'll grant temporary sessions to Web applications for new users on the new profile.
```

you should read the rest of this section. tells you about getting new keys and how many of the new functions like setFBML do not require a session key.

[Here is the page](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/New_Design_Platform_Changes)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for might be the "Offline Access" extended permission...

see: the [Facebook developers wiki on **Extended Permissions**](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions)